# Netsuite Map Reduce yielding

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I read in documentation that soft limits on governance cause map reduce scripts to yield and reschedule. My problem is I cannot see in docs where it explains what happens in the yield. Is the getInputData called again to regather the same data set ok to be mapped or is the initial data set persisted somewhere and already mapped and reduced records are Excluded from processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With yielding, the `getInputData` stage is not called again. From the docs;

> If a job monopolizes a processor for too long, the system can
>   naturally finish the job after the current map or reduce function has
>   completed. In this case, **the system creates a new job to continue
>   executing remaining key/value pairs**. Based on its priority and
>   submission timestamp, the new job either starts right after the
>   original job has finished, or it starts later, to allow
>   higher-priority jobs processing other scripts to execute. For more
>   details, see SuiteScript 2.0 Map/Reduce Yielding.

This is different from server restarts or interruptions, however.